# Do we really need to leave materials below the completed structure?

Tags: glory-to-rome, card-sleeves

According to the official rules, after completing the structure these things happen:

> When you complete a structure, take its Site card and tuck it 
>   underneath the top edge of your Camp so that the gold coins are 
>   showing. The materials stay with the completed structure.

According to that, the materials used to build this structure need to stay below, for the whole game.

Anyway, the buildings stacked on the 2-3 materials, especially when you've put your cards into sleeves, are still moving a bit, and they make some chaos because of that stacking.

I'm wondering if they could be just put away from the game, after completing the building? I was looking for the others buildings rules, trying to search any situation, when materials of completed building could matter in any way.

Do you know any situation of this kind? Do you think I can remove them from the game safely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the base game there is no building that interact with the materials, so, in this case, the answer is yes, you can remove them from the game safely.

But in "Glory to Rome Promo Cards" set you have three buildings that do interact with the materials. Castra Praetoria, Solarium and Watch Post. For the first two cards the kind of interaction is not important here, they move materials upon building completion, after that you do that you could still remove from the game the rest of materials. But Watch Post states : `you may use a CRAFTSMAN action to tear down one of you completed buildings. Add foundation to your hand and materials to your stockpile`. 
So if you are playing with that card the answer is no, you cannot remove them from the game safely.

(I hope that my answer is understandable ... I am not english native speaker)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the answer I was looking for - didn't know about the additional cards. Anyway, after few more plays remaining materials below the buildings seems not that bad at all - so I wouldn't probably be removing them.

Anyway, thank you for the rules clarification!